# (Collectionview inside UITableview cell ) Collectionview layout is updating after scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell, cells are of dynamic width depending upon text.The problem I am facing is when i scroll the TableView after that collection inside cell is appearing correct.

Here is what I did, I called `reloadData` after datasource is set and also called `invalidateLayout` but not working

Here is what I did,
Inside tableViewCell class,

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
CGSize calCulateSizze =[[datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] sizeWithAttributes:NULL];
NSLog(@"%f     %f",calCulateSizze.height, calCulateSizze.width);
calCulateSizze.width = calCulateSizze.width+20;
calCulateSizze.height = 35;
return calCulateSizze;
}

#pragma mark - Public
- (void)setCellData:(id)pData {
GSHColumns *column = (GSHColumns*)pData;
if (column.options.count > 0) {
    datasource = column.options;
    [_collectionView reloadData];
    [_collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    }
    [titleLabel setText:column.displayName];
}
```

Here is what it looks like before scrolling

[image]

and after scrolling,

[image]

Comment: [_collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout]; comment this line and check

Comment: same output....

Comment: brother update your question with cellForItemAtIndexPath this delegates method